# file_get_contents is doing strange on server

Tags: php, json

this is a script that gives you a direct mp3 download link from a youtube video id, variable $gg is the video id

So when i run this code on my xampp locally it runs fine and returns me a **direct** download link but when i try to run this code on my [hosts server](http://elmusic.ml/gh.php) it returns a link but not a direct link but a download page what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
$gg = '6Y1Emb7Jyks';
$site = 'http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/widget/button/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$gg;
$html = file_get_contents($site);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");
for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
       $href = $hrefs->item($i);
       $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
}
$lol = 'http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/'.$url;
echo $lol;
```

Comment: So, what does this code do? What is it doing wrong? What is the output? What should the output be?

Comment: it gives you a direct link of a mp3 file of a youtube video id when i run it local on xampp it works fine but when i run it on my server it gives me a download page but i want a direct link also on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out myself i had to follow the redirect

final code

```
<?php
$gg = '6Y1Emb7Jyks';
$site = 'http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/widget/button/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$gg;
$html = file_get_contents($site);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");
for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
   $href = $hrefs->item($i);
   $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
}
$lol = 'http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/'.$url;



$url= $lol;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$a = curl_exec($ch); 

$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 
echo $url;
```